# React Router not displaying matching components unless page is refreshed

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, redux-toolkit

My application redirects a user to a different route upon button click, but does not render the component with the matching route, unless the page is refreshed. I’ve recently refactored my application to use Redux Toolkit, as well as updating my dependencies, and now experiencing routing issues.

Here is my related dependencies list and my route setup:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
}

// App.js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

<Router>
    <NavBar />
        <div>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
              <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
              <Route path='/signup' component={Signup} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
</Router>

// NavBar
<Typography>
    <Button component={Link} to='/'>
      Home
    </Button>
</Typography>
<Button component={Link} to='/login'>Login</Button>
<Button component={Link} to='/signup'>Signup</Button>

// Login
<small>
    Don't have an account? Sign up{' '}
        <Router>
            <Link to='/signup'>here</Link>
        </Router>
</small>

// Signup
<small>
    Already have an account? Login{' '}
        <Router>
            <Link to='/signup'>here</Link>
        </Router>
</small>
```

Known areas where buggy behavior occurs:

- Clicking the `Home button` on navigation will change url to `'/'` but does not render the `Home component`.
- Clicking the `Login button` on navigation will change url to `'/login'` but does not render the `Login component`.
- Clicking the `Signup button` on navigation will change url to `'/signup'` but does not render the `Signup component`.

Attempted solutions:

- Using `onClick={() => history.push('/')}` renders the correct component for the action but does not change the url route. Example: when user is currently at Home url `'/'` route, clicking the `NavBar`’s signup button will render the `Signup` component, but does not change the url route to `'/signup'`. Upon refresh, the user is brought back to url route `'/'`.
- Use withRouter(withStyles(styles)(Login))
- Have the `BrowserRouter` wrap App in `index.js` file like this `<BrowserRouter><App></BrowserRouter>`
- Use `withRoute` like this `component={withRouter(Login)}`
- Check the order of routes
- Try different imports like this `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router' instead of 'react-router-dom'`
- Wrap the url link like this `<Button color='inherit' component={Link} to={'/'} />`
- NavBar Button’s will render component, but now the url route does not change with this code `onClick={() => history.push('/login’)}`
- Use `Link` like this `<Link to='/'><Button>Home</Button></Link>`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Get rid of the additional `Router`s in your nested components. You should only have one at the root of your application.

Comment: Ok just removed the additional Router, thanks. The bug stills occurs, unfortunately.

Comment: Remove ***all*** the extraneous `Router` components from ***all*** nested components, you only need one `Router` to provide a routing context for all `Link`, `Route`, `Switch`, and `Redirect` components. Once you've done this please update your question to include the *current* code that still has an issue. If possible please do try to create a *running* codesandbox that accurately reproduces your issue that we can inspect and live debug in.

Comment: That was it! There were additional Router components that I wasn't aware existed in my nested components. Deleted them all, except for the one that existed in App.js. Thank you @lawrence-witt and @drew-reese!